# OleDbCommand Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, oledb, insert-into, oledbcommand

I'm getting a syntax error in INSERT INTO statement and I can't figure out why. I've checked several different SO questions that were almost exactly the same as my problem and after changing my code this way and that way it still isn't working.

```
        var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};", oldDb);
        var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);
        cnn.Open();

        //make new access table
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = cnn;
            command.CommandText = String.Format("CREATE TABLE [{0}] ([Tag] string, [Text] string)", newTable + "_Diff");
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                //table already exists
            }
        }

        //fill access table
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = cnn;
            command.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO [{0}] (Tag, Text) VALUES (?, ?)", newTable + "_Diff");
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Tag", ""));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Text", ""));
            for (int i = 0; i < (diffText.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                command.Parameters["Tag"].Value = diffTag[i];
                command.Parameters["Text"].Value = diffText[i];
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        cnn.Close();
```

Creating the table is working so I know there's not a problem with my connection, there's just something it doesn't like about my insert statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your insert command put text inside a square bracket, "text" is a keyword

```
command.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO [{0}] (Tag, [Text]) 
                                    VALUES (?, ?)", newTable + "_Diff");
```

also make sure you are including your values with single quote

> values ('?','?')

hope this works

Comment: Ahhhh I thought I had that! I must have taken the brackets out when changing other things. Thanks for taking the time to point that out for me Karthik

Comment: I'm trying to select this as the answer but after I click the check mark it takes it away...I'll try again later

Comment: yeah.. I can see my reputation going up and down :(